# Javascript memory leak setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, javascript-debugger

Does any one know why memory consumption stays constant here ?

```
var count = 0;
$(init);

function init(){
    var node =  document.querySelector('.logs');

    function check(){
        var uArr = new Uint16Array(100);
        log(node, uArr.length);
        setTimeout(check,100);
    }   
    setTimeout(check,100);
}      


function log(node, text){
    if( count % 30  == 0 ){
        node.innerHTML = '';
    }
    var child = document.createElement('div');
    child.innerText = 'count ' + (count++) + " arr len "  + text;
    node.appendChild(child);
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/V99Eb/11/

Reason why it should linearly increase memory allocation is:  the 'check' method calls itself inside it's definition, so the closure variables will be available to the inside check method execution, which then again creates an execution  context for the test function and so on.

Also, in every execution, we create a memory block of Uint16Array, which I believe is allocated in the heap, and should never get de-allocated since it is reachable from the closure.

Memory Profile:
[image]

Looking  at the memory timeline, it does not seem to increase memory allocation as the time increases. Is this the expected behavior ?

Comment: Why does your title claim a memory leak issue when in fact you're demonstrating that there is no memory leak?

Comment: `uArr` is only a local variable whose lifetime is only the current execution of `check()`.  As soon as one invocation of `check()` finishes, that invocation's local variables are eligible for garbage collected because there is no longer any code that can reach them.  The only variable that survives indefinitely in the closure is `node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uArr` is just a local variable that is allocated, used, and then garbage collected after `check()` exits. And there is no closure inside `check()`. `setTimeout()` is invoked (but not defined) by `check()`.

[This page on Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) may be helpful.

While it is true that if there are N calls to `check()`, there would have been N closures created (as well as N copies of `node`), `setTimeout()` will release its reference to `check()` after it calls it. Therefore, there is no leak there either.

Comment: Your first sentence is not quite true.  If you put a call to an async function with an anonymous completion callback function as an argument in a `for` loop that does N iterations, you will get N separate closures.  The layout determined that there would be a closure, but the N closures themselves were created as the code executed because of the path of execution.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are correct. Thanks! I've modified my answer.